# Firing event in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events

I have following code:

```
handleValidate = (value: string, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
const { onValueChange } = this.props;
const errorMessage = this.validateJsonSchema(value);

if (errorMessage == null) {
  // it is sure that JsonInputRef.current exists
  this.JsonInputRef.current!.setCustomValidity('');

  onValueChange && onValueChange(value, e);
} else {
  if (this.JsonInputRef.current) {
    this.JsonInputRef.current.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
  }
}
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps: JsonInputProps) {
  if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
    this.validateJsonSchema(this.props.value || '');
  }
}
```

Is is a good practice to fire an event in `componentDidMount` or better is to implement it `setTimeout` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props.

You **may call setState() immediately** in `componentDidUpdate()` but note that **it must be wrapped in a condition**.

> **Note:**
>  `componentDidUpdate()` will not be invoked if
>   `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false.

Read more about [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).